# JPQL Average Time Difference

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have order bills and good receive bills. Any bill can have multiple bill items. One order bill item may have none or more receive bill items.

I want to calculate the lead time, which is the average time difference between the order and the good receipt in a JPQL (Java Persistance Query Language) query in days. I use EclipseLink 2.4 as the persistence provider.

This is the query I attempted. Is there any way I can take the average lead time using JPQL ?

```
    jpql = "Select avg(b.createdAt - rb.createdAt) "
            + " from BillItem bi "
            + " join bi.bill b "
            + " joib bi.referanceBillItem rbi "
            + " join rbi.bill rb "
            + " where b.billType in :bts "
            + " and rb.billType in :rbts "
            + " and bi.item=:amp "
            + " and b.createdAt between :fd and :td "
            + " ";
```